# Structured Data Testing Tool: "The value provided for image must be a valid URL."

Tags: image, schema.org, microdata

I can't resolve an error which is not obvious and the error message is the worst possible.

The error is in a blogPosting. The image is in the cloud and is proven to be there on the address I stated in the Microdata.

```
<a itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject" href="<%= story_url %>" data-image-src = "<%= data_image_src %>">
    <link itemprop="url" href="<%= data_image_src %>" />
    <meta itemprop="height" content="100" />
    <meta itemprop="width" content="100" />  
</a>
```

When I clicked on the error it points the `<a>` element and the error is:

> The value provided for image must be a valid URL.

Curiously enough this passes for most of the images. Those that failed were SVG (fair enough to fail as I discovered that they can't). But I converted them to PNG and they still don't want to pass the test.

Example of successful image:
https://xxx.cloudfront.net/5694d5d8b058e5186e000001
Failed image:
https://xxx.cloudfront.net/apple-small.png

Comment: Do you get the error also when pasting the code into the SDTT, or only when testing your URL? If also when pasting the code: please include the exact markup that gives this error (the markup in your question gives no errors)

Comment: Re. your edit/solution: Interesting. Could you please add this as an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of tries I removed the dash from the image name and now It's working without errors. I didn't find this resolution anywhere and It's not in the documentation or at least I didn't find it. Still this looks like a very suspicious cause but...

Comment: For me it was `svg` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was testing metadata from a site generated for serving on localhost. what solved it for me was adding a valid TLD onto the URL - for example `localhost.com`.

`my.localhost` does not work for some reason, even though localhost is a valid TLD.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the test was failing when I used a `.test` domain but worked when I changed it to `.com`.